# Is Asp.net mvc4 soap, rest or neither?

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, soap

Sorry if this sounds a stupid question. Currently studying asp.net mvc4. I know the asp.net web api is almost exclusively 'rest'. Is the mvc4 either soap or rest or as i suspect a webform with more structure & options?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't either, really.

It's not SOAP, as that is an XML protocol used by web services.

Web applications doesn't follow the REST guidelines very well, neither Webforms nor MVC.

REST is simply how the different requests in HTML were intended to be used, for example using a PUT request for updating a resource and a DELETE request for removing a resource. A web application generally uses a POST request for all kinds of changes.

One reason that web aplications are so bad at following REST is that the applications are more complicated than what HTML was originally planned for. A web page usually contains several different resources, and can allow several different actions at once, it's not a simple 1 to 1 mapping where one URL represents one resource and one request results in one action.